# which commit is the fix of spring4shell?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, security

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/002546b3e4b8d791ea6acccb81eb3168f51abb15, I have found this commit on spring github, can anyone confirm that this commit is the fix for the spring4shell vulnerability released few days ago?

Regards,

reference: https://github.com/SAP/project-kb/blob/vulnerability-data/statements/CVE-2022-22965/statement.yaml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this commit indeed fixes Spring4Shell vulnerability. It blocks deserialization of request parameters which do not start with `name` or end with `Name`, which is essential for exploitation as it uses request parameters starting with `class.`. Vulnerability analysis can be found [here](https://www.lunasec.io/docs/blog/spring-rce-vulnerabilities/), for example.